# Unable to use data ffetched rom Firebase as items in a dropdown menu duplicate value error when mapped

Tags: firebase, dropdown, riverpod

My code works just fine using a hard coded list of items. But when using fetched items from firebase for use as DropdownMenu items, I get "assertion error: there should be exactly one item with the dropdownbutton's value. Here are pertinent code snippets I used with the difference being only in hardcoding the items or fetching the items from firebase. I have also tried manually itereating over the fetched data instead of using a map fucntion. Same result of potential duplicate items.

What am I doing worng? Thanks for your help as I ma befuddled to say the least.

```
child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                        dropdownColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                        hint: Text(
                          "Category",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: Device.screenType == ScreenType.mobile
                                ? 16.sp
                                : 18.sp,
                          ),
                        ),
                        value: productCategory,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration.collapsed(
                          hintText: '',
                        ), //removes underline from dropdown widget
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        iconSize: Device.screenType == ScreenType.mobile
                            ? 18.sp
                            : 22.sp,
                        elevation: 16,
                        validator: (value) => value == 'Category'
                            ? 'Please  select product category'
                            : null,
                        items: categoryItems.map(
                          (cat) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              // key: dropdownKeys[cat.id],
                              value: cat.id,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.check,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: Device.screenType ==
                                            ScreenType.mobile
                                        ? 16.sp
                                        : 20.sp,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 3.w,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    cat,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: Device.screenType ==
                                              ScreenType.mobile
                                          ? 16.sp
                                          : 20.sp,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ).toList(),
                        // items: dropdownMenuItems,
                        onChanged: (dropdownValue) {
                          ref
                              .read(categoryProvider.notifier)
                              .categoryOnChanged(dropdownValue.toString());
                        },
                      ),
```

Provider and controllers:

```
final categoryProvider = StateNotifierProvider<Category, List<Category>>(
  (ref) => Category(id: '', imageUrl: '', name: ''),
);

class Category extends StateNotifier<List<Category>> {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String imageUrl;

  List get productCategory => state;

  Category({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.imageUrl,
  }) : super(<Category>[]);

  categoryOnChanged(String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return name;
    }
    return name;
  }

  Future getCategoryLabels() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('categories').get().then(
      (QuerySnapshot categorySnapshot) {
        for (var element in categorySnapshot.docs) {
          state = [
            ...state,
            Category(
              id: element.get('categoryId'),
              name: element.get('name'),
              imageUrl: element.get('image'),
            )
          ];
        }
      },
    );
    // if (kDebugMode) {
    //   print(state);
    // }
    // return state;
  }
}
```

Supplemental code to help understand what is going on added below.
First here's the console output after I tried a manual iteration of data fetched from firebase and printed out the dropDown keys:

{DyH4AF3v1QEnuvfDwB6b: [#62d46],
OxF7EvBOZxsCzSUBXsE0: [#0f7c2], Q22xgxoMxWOVJ9yH7Fx0: [#d390d], hWtHgAsf5GFWASsB8DGw: [#b90d0], sxRbMsr3H249mZinYuWl: [#02c50]}
flutter: {DyH4AF3v1QEnuvfDwB6b: [#f2443],
OxF7EvBOZxsCzSUBXsE0: [#d061d], Q22xgxoMxWOVJ9yH7Fx0: [#61367], hWtHgAsf5GFWASsB8DGw: [#8fe0d], sxRbMsr3H249mZinYuWl: [#85724]}

Why do I have 2 sets of key-value pairs from one print statement and showing exact same keys with different values? I only have 5 key-value pairs of data but now getting 10 key-value pairs of data values. This may speak to the problem but lost as to how this could happen. Below is my code snippet retrieving the data for use as dropdown menu items.

```
Map<String, Key> dropdownKeys = {};
    for (var cat in categoryList) {
      dropdownKeys[cat.id] = UniqueKey();
    }
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownMenuItems = [];
    for (var cat in categoryList) {
      dropdownMenuItems.add(
        DropdownMenuItem(
          key: dropdownKeys[cat.id],
          value: cat.id,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.check,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: Device.screenType == ScreenType.mobile ? 16.sp : 20.sp,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 3.w,
              ),
              Text(
                cat.name,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize:
                      Device.screenType == ScreenType.mobile ? 16.sp : 20.sp,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    print(dropdownKeys);
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-initialize the productCategory variable to ensure that when it is fetched from firebase, its first value is in the dropDownMenuItems.

Changed final String productCategory = 'Category"; to String? productCategory;
Problem solved.